# What is the time_step and how many iterations required for convergence purpose in fluids simulation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, simulation

My question seems elementary:

I use a new numerical method to do fluids dynamics simulation. I use t=0.001s as the time step. But I don´t know how many iterations I need to achieve velocity convergence, because I see the velocity still increases even the iterations was 1000. I want to ask the experienced scientist usually how many iterations do I need and how it is related to time step, typically in **fluids dynamics** area. I understand it depends on the method you use. But I just want get a general guidance. For example , if I want to model a real world 1 hour, what is the time step and iterations I should use? Thanks!

Comment: This question, while similar in spirit to questions I've had myself, is too broad and under specified. Choosing the time step for a numerical method is often both problem- and method-dependent. (Both stability and error control are pertinent issues.) perhaps you could give us more information?

Answer (score 1):

**Elements of answer:**

Lots of fluid dynamics methods rely on explicit, time-marching schemes; for this kind of schemes, a classical convergence condition is the Courant-Friedrichs-Lewy condition. It can be understand fairly simply: if you have a wave propagating in a discrete spatial grid, if you want you scheme to remain stable the time for the wave to propagate from one grid point to another should not be shorter than the integration time. Basically, it means that the waves cannot propagate faster than the information (which is reasonable). As you understand from what precedes, this condition is spatial resolution-dependent.

In one dimension, is can be express as follow:
$$
C = \frac{u \Delta t}{\Delta x} \leq C_{\rm max}
$$
$C$ is the Courant number, with $u$ the velocity of your fastest wave, $\Delta t$ your timestep, $\Delta x$ your spatial resolution, and $C_{\rm max}$ a given value which constrains your scheme. Typically, for explicit schemes in fluid dynamics, $C_{\rm max} \sim 1$. Then, for a given resolution $\Delta x$, you can deduce your timestep $\Delta t$.

Comment: @MBR.So if I have a tetrahedron mesh, the resolution is something like the average volumn of tetrahedrons?

Comment: @abc the resolution would be the minimum size of your tetrahedrons I guess (I'm not so familiar with tetrahedron mesh).